# How to automatically send an SMS if a call is missed?

Tags: sms, automation, missed-calls

Due to a busy schedule, missed call are a constant, and many times the person calling insists on keep calling until I answer.

The ideia is to automatically send an SMS with a pre-defined message to let the caller know that I'm on the phone or otherwise busy, and that I will be returning the call as soon as possible.

So, how can I send an automatic SMS for missed calls?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround using Tasker:

**Profile (or Trigger)**

Create a Profile which allows sending to contact with the missed call:

- Goto Profiles Tab and click the "+"
- Event >> Phone >> Missed Call
- Tap back to exit from this window

**Task**

You will notice as soon exit, you will be prompted to link this to a Task

- Scroll all the way up the Task list select "New Task + "
- You can name this Task *SendSMSmc* or anything.
- Click "+" to add new Action
- Phone >> Send SMS [Number:%CNUM Message ( e.g I am currently busy at the moment, I'll call later)
- Tap back to exit from this task
- Press back all the way to exit (Your task is saved)

*Explanation: When a call is received, and even  if you are not able to answer it, 
the "Missed Call trigger" allows Tasker to send a message containing the body test:
"I am currently busy at the moment, I'll call later" to the missed call number" where %CNUM is the missed call number.*

Hope this helps other users well

Answer (score -1):

Press and hold the RED button when the call arrives, this will show you the message icon, then drag your RED button to the message icon which will give the SMS message options while disconnecting.

Comment: The OP asks for automatic

Comment: This is call rejection feature